# Laravel any new routes suddenly stop working even though nothing has changed

Tags: laravel, routes

I have had some weird issues in the past with Laravel routing, however they could usually be fixed with some form of logical solution, eg. clearing the route cache, or a genuine user error...

But this one is very strange. I have been developing this site for a few weeks and using the /admin routes for some time, but today anything related to /admin or logging in is resulting in a 404 | not found from Laravel. And now even adding any new routes is not working, including very basic ones.

eg. the home page is routed like this:

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
```

But adding:

```
Route::get('/test', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'home'])->name('test');
```

To my web.php routes is also bringing me to a 404.

Just to explain my development environment, I am on Windows and I have tried serving this with both "php artisan serve", and also with XAMPP, but both are giving me the same issue. I won't bother explaining the XAMPP set up, because this was literally working yesterday and nothing has changed, but with php artisan serve it takes me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/".. this doesn't require any special hacking.. it usually just works.

**What have I done differently today?**

So all I have done today is:

1. Added a new command with "php artisan make:command SomeCommandIStartedMaking"

This surely hasn't screwed anything up? I've even deleted the command and reset to my last commit just in case and still the routes are screwed.

2. In my windows "hosts" file I added "127.0.0.1    somedomain.com"

So this sounds like the kind of thing that would have an effect on routing, and it's where I first noticed the issue.. but since then I have "ipconfig /flushdns", I have removed the entries from my host file, and I have cleared my laravel routes and caches, but still the issue remains.

I am really stuck on this one. Also finally! I have done a route:list and I can clearly see the routes showing up like expected, but I can assure you that nothing has changed since yesterday so this seems like another issue.

Here is a dump of web.php, because I know this will be asked for:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// Frontend
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
Route::get('/instagram-gallery', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'instagramGallery'])->name('instagram-gallery');
Route::get('/{pageAlias}', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'index'])->name('page');

Route::post('/contact-send', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'contactSend'])->name('contact-send');

Route::get('/test', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'home'])->name('test');

// Admin
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'is_admin']], function(){
    Route::get('/',                         [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin');
    Route::get('/search/{table}',           [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'search'])->name("admin-search");
    Route::get('/browse/{table}',           [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'browse'])->name("admin-browse");
    Route::get('/create/{table}',           [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'create'])->name("admin-create");
    Route::get('/edit/{table}/{id}',        [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'edit'])->name("admin-edit");
    Route::get('/manage-account',           [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'manageAccount'])->name("admin-manage-account");
    Route::get('/documentation/{subject?}', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'documentation'])->name("admin-documentation");
    
    Route::post('/create/{table}/action',   [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'createAction'])->name("admin-create-action");
    Route::post('/edit/{table}/{id}/action',[App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'editAction'])->name("admin-edit-action");
    Route::post('/delete',                  [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'deleteAction'])->name("admin-delete-action");
    Route::post('/wysiwyg-upload',          [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'wysiwygUpload'])->name("wysiwyg-upload");
    Route::post('/manage-account-action',   [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'manageAccountAction'])->name("admin-manage-account-action");
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

One thing to add, is that "/contact" resolves just fine which is using the '/{pageAlias}' route as shown above, so some are working and some aren't. How should I trouble shoot this I don't even know where to start :(

Any help would be hot! This is so frustrating haha! Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of your routes - the code will run line by line trying to find a matching route.

Once it hits

```
Route::get('/{pageAlias}', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'index'])->name('page');
```

It will match /test and naturally stop - never reaching your next route.

To solve this, your specific route `/test` needs to be defined before your general "catch-all" route `/{pageAlias}`

Comment: You are so right!! I must have added that recently without even realising! I am so sorry for such a basic question! It's fixed, thank you. Some times my brain goes to mush after a long day of coding... so sorry :(

Comment: @Zephni Don't be sorry - this happens even to most Senior Developers; it is only natural when working with so much information that you can stare yourself blind to an error. Any programmer will continuously make mistakes, mistakes aren't the problem, how you recover from them is, and you just recovered :)

Answer (score 2):

This might due to cache so run following commands

```
php aritsan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

To use single command:

```
PHP artisan optimize
```